# Storing and Accessing a Range of Numbers / Dates in MySQL

Tags: mysql, range

I need to store a range of numeric or datetime values in MySQL, preferably in a single column. Unfortunately, as there are no real array or set data-types in MySQL, likewise it seems that there is no range data-type, so I'm a bit at an impasse here, hoping to come up with something smart.

Common use cases for a range would be e.g. storing the start and end times of an event, or the minimum and maximum prices of a given product.

In my case, I simply need to store the year(s) a book was written. In some cases, there is ambiguity and the year I have on record may be e.g. 810-820. Of course one way to go would be to have separate `year_min` and `year_max` columns, and then have identical data stored in both columns in case there is no variance.

Yet only a fraction of the entries I have would actually need to have such a range stored, and I'd much love to just query a simple `BETWEEN 750 AND 850` for example -- and avoid both having a `WHERE` hit on two columns, as well as the redundant duplication of data in 98% of the cases.

What's your recommended approach? Any best practice tips? I know how to tune up decent two-column queries. I'm hoping there's another way to go about this... (And no, I'm not likely to switch to PostgreSQL *just* to have the benefit of their [range types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/rangetypes.html).)

Comment: nice work not suggesting delimited fields of any sort.

Comment: @pala_ delimited fields as strings would be a nightmare. I wouldn't even be able to deal with numbers as numbers. I did think about hacking the `DECIMAL` type for this. I thought about it for about seven seconds before moving on. Could always look into bastardizing geometric data types. But what's the `POINT` eh, it sounds like two columns it is.

Comment: hopefully you didnt detect sarcasm in my comment - it was genuine :)

Comment: Yes I took it as a genuine complement @pala_. Storing CSV strings and using `LIKE '%,foo,%` queries are the `(ice|s)*cream` of the noobsy DB world for sure.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend going with a two column solution, despite that it is not that sexy or clever.  Suppose you implement this with one column.  Then your database becomes non relational, because a given record and column now points to *multiple* values (`year_min` and `year_max`).  So even though your schema might appear tidy, you might lose that benefit in the form of more difficult queries.

Comment: .. and just set year_min = year_max = publication year for those that only have the one edition

Comment: Indeed. Suppose my filesystem isn't really going to bloat to a point of concern for that extra column. But would a range data-type make it non-relational by definition? PostgreSQL implements several range types and even lets you define your own... and I reckon you will still be able to use `BETWEEN` as one would on regular integer columns.